# How to add the groupId of a maven module to the name / presentation in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm a fairly new IntelliJ user with Eclipse Background. I've loaded a multimodule maven project. Some of these modules happen to have sub modules with unique groupIds, but repeating artifactId names (like api, commons etc.) IntelliJ imports them with the artifactId and numbers them visually. Like "commons (1) groupId", "commons (2) groupId" etc. This looks rather silly :(

In Eclipse I'm able to provide a pattern of the maven project import to specify that the name used to present a module is eg. "groupId.artifactId" with or without a version.

I'm currently unable to find the IntelliJ configuration, or a plugin to achieve a similar presentation which i prefer even for single module projects. Thanks for any hints!

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-56116 and the 2 linked requests.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment ... Sad that this takes a decade to be improved :(